# strange cursor behaviour with canvas and body element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, mouse

I have a html document containing some javascript code and a canvas element.

In the javascript bit, I'm using the following code to hide the mouse pointer:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
```

And something really strange happens: **the mouse pointer is hidden only when the mouse is over the canvas element, but is visible when the mouse is over the rest of the body**.

I've tested this in Firefox 41 and Chrome 46. Exact same thing.

**Does anybody know why this could be happening, and how it can be prevented?**

To give some more context info: I'm making an interactive page, where the user first needs to click on some buttons with the mouse (so the mouse pointer needs to be visible initially), and then there's a period where interaction happens only by pressing keys, and the mouse pointer is distracting, so I want to make it disappear. Then after that, I need to resurrect the mouse pointer so the user can click on buttons again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

Have you considered using `* { cursor: none; }` in your CSS, it should remove the cursor off the whole screen in the browser window but I'm not sure why you want to do this.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0wh4rcyb/

Comment: Hi Torean, thanks for your comment.

I'm not sure I can use your solution.

I'll explain a bit more about why I need to do this:

Comment: does the solution work for you? if you stumble across other issues, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `<body>` only has the height of your canvas element+ margins :

```js
document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
```

```css
body{border: 1px solid;}
canvas {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

you can solve this by setting the width and height of your body to `100vw` and `100vh` :

```js
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'none';
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
html, body{
    margin: 0
}
canvas {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```